# Custom included extras Android (AOSP) Compilation

Tags: android, android-source

For reasons, I want to compile the AOSP 4.3.3 tree with the 'user' (aosp_deb-user) build (and not the user-debug / eng builds).

However I would like to specify that I:

- would like the su package included (system/extras)
- possibly (but less importantly) remove some things I do not need in my testing (therefore speed compilation up) - such as chromium app / camera app / whatever.

Could anyone let me know how to do this?

I already attempted changing the build tag in the su 'Android.mk' to user (which was the old way of doing it) - but it now gives me an error stating I must request in my product packages, however i am unsure where this is.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's (mainly) the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable that controls which modules are installed. That variable is set in the product makefiles, which form hierarchies of makefiles. The leaf file for a concrete product is usually device/vendorname/productname/productname.mk or similar, in your case device/asus/deb/aosp_deb.mk. In that file you'll find a couple of inclusions:

```
$(call inherit-product, device/asus/deb/device.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/aosp_base.mk)
```

If you following the trail of `inherit-product` breadcrumbs you'll eventually encounter all PRODUCT_PACKAGES assignments, at least one of which will list the modules that you want to exclude. (The SRC_TARGET_DIR variable in the example above points to the build/target directory.)